# How to provide a fake header search path for cocoa-pod itself?

Tags: ios, cocoapods

In the Specs repo, there is a pod. It used to build correctly and work, but the library creators changed the way they distribute the files to iOS framework, and with it some headers.

Pod is called `LibNameSDK`. New framework is called `LibName.framework`, and it's public headers are now referencing sibling files by including the lib name:

```
#import <LibName/HeaderName.h>
```

I wanted to create a new podspec for the new version, but I am failing to keep its name the same. If I use a `podspec` file that's still called `LibNameSDK`, none of the imports work when building *the pod itself*. Unless the podspec and its folder are changed to `LibName`, compiler cannot resolve headers.

The question is, can this be fixed with some additional podspec configurations? How to cheat a pod to look for headers in non-existing path?
I was thinking either custom header search paths for the pod or some fake path creation, but I cannot find similar references on the web: all problems seems to be about pod usage, not podspec creation.

The `.podspec` for the reference, omitting summary and such:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name     = 'LibNameSDK'
  s.version  = '1.2.3'
  s.platform = :ios, '5.0'
  s.requires_arc = true
  s.source_files = 'LibName.framework/Versions/A/Headers/*.h'
  s.vendored_frameworks = 'LibName.framework'
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it in the [spec docs](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#header_dir).

```
spec.header_dir = 'LibName'
```

did the trick just fine, all includes both in the project and in the pod itself work correctly.

Comment: I have same issue, but the problem is I can import as #import "header.h" easily anywhere but as #import<LibName/header.h> doesn't work !! the second one will show me an error file not found !! do you have any idea whats going on? is there any problem with my pod spec? cause it works the first way!